# unwanted row when selecting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The following `SELECT` query doesn't work properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    student.firstname,
    student.lastname,
    student.emailAddress,
    cast(memberslist.dateJoined as DATE) as dateJoined
FROM student, memberslist
WHERE 
    memberslist.orgName = 'Elite League of Information Technology Students'
    AND memberslist.joined = 'yes'
```

**I have 2 tables: `student` and `memberslist`**

`memberslist` table:
[image: memberslist table]

`student` table:
[image: student table]

and when I run the query, the result is the following:

[image: SQL query results]

I don't understand why it gives me the row `pakalu` when the `WHERE` was 'Elite League of Information Technology Student'

Comment: You are not joining the student and memberslist tables on any column, hence these results

Comment: You should consider using the `orgCode` instead of the `orgName`. Unless you're building a search feature, it's a good idea to query by a short, unique identifier instead of the long name.

Comment: it is intended for a view, list of members. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of implicit join is discouraged, you need following query:

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, s.emailAddress, cast(m.dateJoined as DATE) as dateJoined 
FROM student s INNER JOIN memberslist m
ON s.emailAddress = m.emailAddress
WHERE m.orgName = 'Elite League of Information Technology Students' 
  AND m.joined = 'yes'
```

Comment: ohh i was thinking about it. i knew i have to use a proper join thanks this is an accepted answer